# convert get to post in php

Tags: php

how to convert this PHP code from using the $_GET method to $_POST

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
if (checkCreditCard ($_GET['CardNumber'], $_GET['CardType'], $ccerror, $ccerrortext)) {
$ccerrortext = 'This card has a valid format';
} else {
 echo 'not working';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I can write this code for you. I charge $100/hour with a minimum billed time of two hours, paid up-front. Do you have Paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PHP code to this (changing all instances of $_GET to $_POST):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (checkCreditCard ($_POST['CardNumber'], $_POST['CardType'], $ccerror, $ccerrortext)) {
        $ccerrortext = 'This card has a valid format';
    } else {
         echo 'not working';
    }
}
?>
```

Change your HTML forms opening tag from `<form method="GET" ... >` to `<form method="POST" ... >` ("..." representing other attributes that you may have in the tag)

Answer (score 2):

This is handled on the form side. Instead of setting the  'method' attribute to GET, set it to POST.

This will tell it to pass it as a POST variable, removing the restrictions the GET gives you.

As far as PHP is concerned, it doesn't care if it was GET or POST, aside from the fact that it needs to know which array to look in for the mapping. Even then, the $_REQUEST[] associative array will look in both GET and POST arrays.

If your curious GET not only makes the data easily readable in the URL, it also limits the size of data you can pass (max url length)

Comment: well done, and no undertones were detected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply referring to?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (checkCreditCard($_POST['CardNumber'], $_POST['CardType'], $ccerror, $ccerrortext)) {
        $ccerrortext = 'This card has a valid format';
    } else {
        echo 'not working';
    }
}
?>
```

Though you may have a client-side issue with the form submit like others have mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a PHP problem how data reach it. You might want to use a form or an hidden form for POST method requests:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="CardNumber" value="value">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the $_GET to $_POST everywhere in your script. The main change is on how the data is coming in. This should be handled in the source page from where the data is sent to this script.

Let us consider a simple example:

```
<!-- Login.html -->
<form method='POST' action='yourscript.php'>
Email<input type='text' name='email'></input>
Password<input type='password' name='password'></input>
</form>
```

The only change here is the 'POST' parameter for the method attribute in place of 'GET'